# Deleting previous table when selecting a new table

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="#" onclick="createTable('Table',11)">Table</a>
 </div>
```

In my program I have a button, where a user will select a table and then that table will be displayed. Currently, when a second selection is made, it just adds a table beneath the first table. I would like to just display the current selection. I have tried this:

```
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content" syle="clear:both;">
 <a href="#" onclick="createTable('Table',11)">Table</a>
 </div>
```

And it did nothing. I also tried using a clearfix to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your JavaScript code, as the cause of the behaviour sounds like it's in the `createTable` function.

Comment: Also, `clear` is a CSS property that is used to position things around floated elements (`float` is another CSS property). I'm assuming you expected clear to clear the first table.

Answer (score 1):

Using `style="display:none"` on the table you wish to hide will work.

You could create a function that can easily turn the visibility of just one table on and off depending on the button you click but without your Javascript, I can't really help you.

Feel free to tag me or message me back when you have put in the Javascript and I can try to help you right a function that will do it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

1- Give every table an ID :

```
<table id="table1">..</table>
<table id="table2">..</table>
```

2- In the click handler of your button use the id to hide the table, let's say you want to hide table1

```
document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none"
```

You can also use JQuery functions : [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use JQuery function [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to delete the previously created table, or use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) [to hide the table] and .show() [if u ever need to display the table again].

But,if you post your script,it'll be easier to give a correction,instead of a different solution.